# Javascript function call says undefined but function is defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, undefined

In my html I have the following function call

```
<input value="Roll" onclick="roll()" type="button">
```

which should call the function `roll()` that is defined as follows before:

```
    <head>
    <script language="javascript">
    // roll function
    // roll button pressed to roll the die and update as needed
    function roll(){
        wintotal = document.JForm.totalpoints.value;    
        var validate = Validate();
        var p1total = document.JForm.p1turn.value;
        var p2total = document.JForm.p2turn.value;

        var dienumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (6 - 1 +1)) + 1;

        if (validate){  
            // put together image for die graphic that was rolled
            document.getElementById("dice").innerHTML = '<img src="die_face_'+dienumber+'.png"/>';


        }
        else if (validate == 0){
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML ="ERROR: Play to points not in range";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML ="ERROR: Play to points not in valid integer";
        }
    }  // end roll function
    </script>
</head><body>
```

however when i click the button the HTML page I get an error saying `roll` is undefined even though it is clearly defined above it, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that is `roll` the problem and not the other functions like `Validate` or another?

Comment: Could you post the exact error message you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

I tried that code and it's like you said. Then I deleted that Validate thing and now it works normal. What do you need it for and why? It's not that clear on the example posted!

I'd have written this as a comment, but I haven't got enough reputation... :(

EDIT: Like I said in the comment, if the problem is just checking if the value is an integer or not, you can implement this function.

```
function isInt(n)
{
    return n % 1 === 0;
}
```

Comment: You are correct, i am using the validate function to return a value based on if a text box's value is an integer or not. 
    function Validate(){
 var total = Number(document.JForm.totalpoints.value);
 var good = 1;
 var range = 0;
 var type = 3;
 if (Math.floor(total) == total){
  if ((total >= 50) && (total <= 100)){
   return good;
  }
  else{
   reutrn range;
  } 
 }
 else{
  return type;
 }
}

Comment: You could implement function isInt(n) {return n % 1 === 0;}  to check whether your input is an integer or not!